# Python 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 10

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I have the string 'Leicht bewölkt'. 
The 'ö' is causing the error

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to encode it into utf8 # - *- coding: utf- 8 - *- to the start if the file but it does not work. Could you help me out with that? I just want to print it into the command line and send it to an arduino.

```py
def removeThat(schasch):
    print(schasch)
    schasch = str(schasch).encode('utf8')
    schasch = str(schasch).encode('utf8').replace("ü","ue").replace("ä","ae").replace("ö","oe").replace("ß","sss")
    return schasch
```

Comment: Which character encoding is expected at the Arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace characters before you encode the string into utf8

```py
replacements = {
    'ü': 'ue',
    'ä': 'ae',
    'ö': 'oe',
    'ß': 'ss',
}


def replace_umlauts(text: str) -> str:
    for find, replace in replacements.items():
        text = text.replace(find, replace)
    return text

def encode_text(text: str) -> bytes:
    fixed = replace_umlauts(text)
    return fixed.encode('utf-8')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = 'Leicht bewölkt'
    print(replace_umlauts(text))
    print(encode_text(text))
```

which prints

```
Leicht bewoelkt
b'Leicht bewoelkt'
```